# Editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I need an editor template (aspx or razor, doesn't matter) for editing an integer value which can only have 1 or 0 (for true and false).

the reason I am not using boolean is because of the DB model I have to work with.

I need to show a check box where:

> Check: 1
>
> Uncheck: 0

I have this:

```
@model int? 
@Html.CheckBox("statusID", Model.HasValue && Model.Value == 1)
```

But is not working.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "But is not working.". Perhaps you should be more specific about **HOW** it's not working as expected, rather than expecting us to read your mind.

Comment: I am sorry for that.  It is not working becuase its not taking the proper value and neither is sending it when modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12513382/3622021 to solve the problem you have. Extend the view model with a property decorated with [NotMapped] which translates between your nullable int and a boolean display value.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int? statusID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public bool StatusChecked
    {
        get { return statusID == 1 ? true : false; }
        set { statusID = value ? 1 : 0; }
    }
}
```

Then, just bind to the `StatusChecked` property instead of the `statusID` property with something like this:

```
@model MyViewModel 
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.StatusChecked)
```

Of course, that assumes you have some control over the model type you're allowed to bind to the UI. This won't work if, for some reason, you're stuck with a model of strictly int? as the code above indicates.

Comment: I do have control over my model. It is a LINQ to SQL Classes Model.

Comment: I will test your solution and let you know the results. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: It worked but i need to use it with different models but I just want to use one template.

Example:
Model: Environments
Model: Directives

both have StatusID property but in your example I will have to create 2 tamplates (one for each model)

Comment: You could always have each template implement the IStatusCheck interface and have the UI bind to that. There still may be two implementations of the logic, but only on UI template. Another solution would be to create a custom CheckBoxFor edit template taking a nullable int.